# ESS C-M-x (ess-eval-region-...) emacs shortcut doesn't work

Tags: r, emacs, key-bindings, ess

For some reason the following key combination in emacs doesn't work:

`ess-eval-region-or-function-or-paragraph` (`C-M-x`): Sends the current selected region or function or paragraph.

I'm able to succesfully select it from the window menu, I can use `C-c C-c` and other evaluations succefully, but this one combination isn't responding. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and checked that there shouldn't be any ubuntu shortcuts shadowing that one. Any ideas what could be the cause?

Comment: It works fine for me. Just in case, that binding is `<control>-<meta>-x` not a capital "m". Double check that `C-M-x` is indeed bound to the proper function with `C-h k C-M-x`. If it is, you could try calling `edebug-defun` on its source code and step through to see what is wrong

Comment: It works in my home computer too. Thanks for the good suggestions, it seems that something is capturing the combination, since after `C-h k` the `C-M-x` has no effect, it keeps waiting for the key.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on my Ubuntu Emacs 27.1 (KDE). Trying "C-h k C-M-x" still waits for the input key, like "C-M-x" is not bound.

However, **C-M-S-x** (with shift) works. "C-h k C-M-S-x" writes:

> C-M-x (translated from C-M-S-x) runs the command eval-defun (found in
> emacs-lisp-mode-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function
> in ‘elisp-mode.el’.
>
> It is bound to C-M-x.
> ...

I'm not sure why it's not bound to ess-eval-region-or-function-or-paragraph. Maybe this is a special binding in my setup or javekki's.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30132163)

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Control_R</kbd>+<kbd>Alt_R</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>. If this doesn't work, another issue that could be is that your right <kbd>Alt</kbd> really is <kbd>AltGr</kbd>(ISO_Level3_Shift). If so, you could remap it like it's explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199286/map-right-alt-to-alt-instead-of-altgr).

I have same issue. Don't know why, but <kbd>Control_L</kbd>+<kbd>Alt_L</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> doesn't work. It doesn't do anything. It is not binded to something else. Running `xev` in console and pushing <kbd>Control_L</kbd>+<kbd>Alt_L</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> doesn't show <kbd>x</kbd> being pushed. Tried in tty without GUI still no luck. So, for now I just blame my cheap keyboard.